# Setup Voip Call from SIP Account in php

Tags: php, voip

I have my CMS built in the php, now I want to integrate Voip call on when admin click on the any user's phone number, but I didn't find any solution to get it done. All I have a SIP details of admin and the second user. 
I did tried the example shown in below link but not working:
https://level7systems.co.uk/en/click_to_call_with_php_sip/
it always returning `No final response in fr_timer seconds`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research I have found that SIPML is the solution of my problem, it gives pre-build library to make sip call, below is the demo URL :
https://www.doubango.org/sipml5/call.htm?svn=250

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have VoIP server which supports some kind of API, probably best one is Asterisk or Freeswitch.(I don't know what server you are using, but you will need not only SIP account, but some kind of API too) If you will use Asterisk you can use AMI interface for triggering call. So when you click on number your PHP script needs to connect to Asterisk management interface and trigger a call.

Here are some examples:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+Example:+PHP