# SIP : fsockopen doesn't reponse correct/worng user

Tags: php, sip, voip, sip-server

I have tried many times with multi servers with correct login & password, but i dont get any reponse.

```
$ports = array('5060','5061');
foreach($ports as $port){
$socket = fsockopen("71.170.105.118", $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
fputs($socket, "Action: Login\r\n");
fputs($socket, "UserName: XXX\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Secret: XXX\r\n\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Action: Command\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Command: sip show peers\r\n\r\n");

$wrets=fgets($socket,128);

echo $wrets."¦".$errno."¦".$errstr."\n";

}
```

I'm getting this reponse :

```
¦0¦
¦0¦
```

I'm looking to ensure if the credentials are correct or not to execute my next commands.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about SIP but this looks an awful lot like an HTTP request, except it's missing the very first line containing the method and the request. You set headers but not the request. A little Googling indicated this is necessary, even though I'd have to search more to understand how to use the protocol.

Comment: googled many time, i toke this code from this source :
https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-manager-example-php/

Comment: Ports 5060 and 5061, both on TCP and UDP, are associated to the Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) by IANA. In particular, port 5060 is assigned to clear text SIP, and port 5061 is assigned to encrypted SIP, also known as SIP-TLS (SIP over a TLS, Transport Layer Security, encrypted channel). Unfortunately, the standard TLS (successor of SSL) can only be established over TCP.

Comment: This RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3261 looks like it's using a different protocol

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38409716/setup-voip-call-from-sip-account-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to Asterisk AMI (Asterisk Manager Interface) but it works with another port, you may find correct port in the `manager.conf` file in general section, my contains this:

```
[general]
enabled = yes
port = 5038
bindaddr = 0.0.0.0
displayconnects=no ;only effects 1.6+
```

So, as you can see, the port is 5038 instead of 5060 and 5061, but when I have been trying to connect with your code, it returns only `Asterisk Call Manager/2.10.4 ¦0¦` string, so I rewrited it a little:

```
$socket = fsockopen("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", '5038', $errno, $errstr, 30);
fputs($socket, "Action: Login\r\n");
fputs($socket, "UserName: admin\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Secret: XXXXXXX\r\n\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Action: Command\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Command: sip show peers\r\n\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Action: Logoff\r\n");

while ($wrets=fgets($socket)) {
    var_dump($wrets);
}
```

So, now it works fine

Comment: I'm just user and im not able to see manager.conf, I'm looking to connect to the server as voip software that allows you to make calls like eyebeam.
What im looking for ? is to get reply if i have connected successfully or not

Thank you

Comment: @ElarbiDafrouillah the script that you are trying to use is for managing an Asterisk server, it doesn't help you to check connection as a client